# how to obtain a proportions table based on info from 2 different tables in R

Tags: r, datatable

I have 2 tables: one for my study population, and one for my source population. They are based on 2 DFs with the same variables : patientID, center, year of start of treatment. They each give me the number of patients per center and per year

```
tb1 = table(ART_source$PROGRAM, ART_source$ART_Y)

tb2 = table(ART_study$PROGRAM, ART_study$ART_Y)
```

I need a 3rd table, which shows the proportion of patients in the study population (based on the source population). So something like this:
t3 = table (t2 / t1)
except that of course this doesn't work. 
I could do it manually on excel, but I think there must be a more clever way to do it in R. Your help is much appreciated,

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [ask] and give a [mcve] in your question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited to reflect a column that shouldn't be divided:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- data.frame(id = c("patient1", "patient2", "patient3", "patient4", "patient5"), replicate(5,sample(1:50,5,rep=TRUE)))
df2 <- data.frame(id = c("patient1", "patient2", "patient3", "patient4", "patient5"), replicate(5,sample(1:50,5,rep=TRUE)))

df3 <- data.frame(df1$id, df1[, c(2:6)] / df2[, c(2:6)])

> df1
        id X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1 patient1 15 18  5 49 47
2 patient2 13 32 13 33 21
3 patient3 20 42 32  5 25
4 patient4 32  8 26 32 18
5 patient5 48 49 13 44 13
> df2
        id X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
1 patient1 48 12  6 21 25
2 patient2 18 43  1 14 13
3 patient3 10 18 37 25 13
4 patient4 37  4 47  3 28
5 patient5  9  2 50  1 13
> df3
    df1.id        X1        X2         X3        X4        X5
1 patient1 0.3125000  1.500000  0.8333333  2.333333 1.8800000
2 patient2 0.7222222  0.744186 13.0000000  2.357143 1.6153846
3 patient3 2.0000000  2.333333  0.8648649  0.200000 1.9230769
4 patient4 0.8648649  2.000000  0.5531915 10.666667 0.6428571
5 patient5 5.3333333 24.500000  0.2600000 44.000000 1.0000000
```

Comment: I think @tticona didn't transform the table to data frame.

Comment: Hi, I tried converting the tables to data frames, but when dividing directly it does not let me because I have 2 factor variable (patient ID), and then a year variable. Which is why I can't divide straight up. What I would be dividing is the number of patients that "came up" per center and per year. Ideas?

Comment: They are 2 contingency tables, sorry I forgot to mention that

Comment: Not sure what you mean with 2 contingency tables? I've changed my example to have a column that shouldn't be divided.

Comment: I adjusted your example for my data, and it works beautifully. Thanks a lot Sven!